# Increasing GPIO switching speed

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, raspberry-pi4

I'm working on a little project I wanted to see come to life using a NEOPIXEL WS2812B with a PI 4. I think I might be up against a hardware limitation and I'm curious if there's anyway around it. Heres the code I'm using

```
void send1()
{
    //T1H
    digitalWrite(DATA, HIGH);
    //usleep(0.85);
    //T1L
    digitalWrite(DATA, LOW);
    //usleep(0.4);
}
```

As you can see I've commented out the usleep stuff because I was having issues with the timing and I wanted to see the maximum switching speed I can get.

[image]

With that I get a switching speed of around 1.200us. The neopixels requires a 0.4 and 0.85us switching speed to work properly. Does anyone have any suggestions that can help get that number down? I'm just using a regular gpio pin. I'm rather new to playing around with the pi so I don't know all the tricks.

I did see this on pinout.xyz

> The PWM0 output of GPIO 18 is particularly useful, in combination with
> some fast, direct memory access trickery, for driving devices with
> very specific timings. The WS2812 LEDs on the Unicorn HAT are a good
> example of this in action.

That seems hopeful since the LEDs I'm using are the same model. but it doesn't really say much more about the tricks.

Comment: I haven't tested this myself, but I'm quite sure that neopixels can be used with a raspberry pi. Since the above is the fastest you can get (I'm assuming you're using wiringpi?), this should be fine. Can you share the part that mentiones the required switching speed?

Comment: First step is to move to kernel driver, in case you are running OS on this hardware. If it doesn't help, you need to ensure that your OS supports Real Time operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Direct Answer

You can try any of the following gpio libraries on rpi,

- Rpi.GPIO (https://sourceforge.net/projects/raspberry-gpio-python/)
- Gpiozero (https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/)
- Pigpio (http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/)
- Wiring Pi (deprecated, see [author's statement](http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-deprecated/))

### Further Suggestion

It is not recommened to generate PWM signal directly from Raspberry Pi, because the linux kernel is not designed for real-time application and any other higher priority process could take over CPU from any running process, so basically you cannot make sure to have a constant PWM signal output. Probably NEOPIXEL LED will be flicking or changing color slightly in your case.

If you need better quality of PWM output, you are suggested to use a small I2C PWM module, e.g. many PCA9685-based boards. Your raspberry pi will control the module via I2C interface only when the value need to upadte, so your CPU are saved for your other applications.

Comment: The Pi does have hardware PWM support. I'm not sure it can be used for the task at hand, but in general, they work very nicely.

Comment: I apologize, but this is not an answer. I have full knowledge of the gpio libraries that are available. I also do understand somewhat of the capabilities of the PWM output. This is not what I'm looking for. I'm trying to squeeze performance out of wiringPi. Or for good suggestions on a faster library to use. My main question was how they did it on the unicorn hat.